# Хранение данных из нескольких таблиц

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Возник такой вопрос:

Есть две таблицы: одна содержит некие уникальные значения, вторая содержит имена пользователей.

Мне необходимо пользователям выдавать доступ, исходя из значений в первой таблице, у одного пользователя может несколько этих значений, соответственно и значение может быть ассоциировано с несколькими пользователями.

Отсюда, собственно, и сам вопрос, как это будет лучше сделать, создать третью таблицу куда вносить запись вида пользователь - значение? Или возможно ещё как-то по-другому.
База MySQL.

**Обновление**

Вы, наверное, не так меня поняли, мне не предоставить пользователю привилегии нужно. Постараюсь более подробно изложить суть.

Есть база договоров, у каждого договора есть литера, в зависимости от литеры договора, в его согласовании принимают участие разные пользователи, одну литеру может согласовывать минимум 3 пользователя, а один пользователь может быть согласовантом у нескольких литер.

Исходя из литеры, мне потом надо будет делать автоматическую рассылку email согласовантам.

Надеюсь, так более понятно.

Comment: А зачем Вы хотите выдавать права через ... спину? Почему не пользуетесь командой GRANT...?

Comment: Обновил вопрос.